# How to convert label value on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I try to create a histogram for the duration time of recovery of some system, and raw data is like:

```
+---------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|     Start Time      |      End Time      |  Duration   |
+---------------------+--------------------+-------------+
| 2019-09-01 8:50:04  | 2019-09-02 9:29:35 | 24h 39m 31s |
| 2019-09-01 11:58:32 | 2019-09-02 9:34:21 | 21h 35m 49s |
| 2019-09-02 0:24:56  | 2019-09-02 9:58:02 | 9h 33m 6s   |
+---------------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

To easily calculate, I converted values in the `Duration` column to second (e.g `24h 39m 31s` to 88771) and use this value for the input of `plt.hist()`.

Histogram works fine, but I want to display not seconds but minutes on the label of the x-axis.

[image: output of histogram]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

x = np.array([88771,77749,34386,....])

plt.hist(x, bins=20)
```

How to display the formatted value on axis label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to convert your duration directly into minutes and then make an histogram of that.
However, if for some reason you don't want to change your array you could manually set the xticks using matplotlib [ticker module](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/ticker_api.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
#generate random data
x=np.random.randint(low=0,high=1e4,size=1000)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10), nrows=2,ncols=1,constrained_layout=True)
#Plot data with duration in second
axs[0].hist(x,bins=50)
axs[0].set_xlabel('Duration [sec]')

#Plot data with duration in minutes
axs[1].hist(x,bins=50)
#modify tick labels
ticks=np.round(axs[1].get_xticks()/60)
axs[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ticks))

axs[1].set_xlabel('Duration [min]')
```

the result:

[image]